# Empty RecyclerView when using custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate my `RecyclerView` with data from cloud(`parse.com`). However, The end result is an Empty `RecyclerView` . Though I am able to retrieve the data from cloud, I don't see any on the Screen.

Here is the main Activity Code:

```
public class BigBoard extends ActionBarActivity {

private List<Person> persons;
private RecyclerView rv;
RVAdapter adapter;
String a,b;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "app-id", "client-key");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);
    adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);


    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();

}

private void initializeData(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Credentials");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> credentialList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(int i=0;i<credentialList.size();i++)
                {
                    a=credentialList.get(i).getString("Name");
                    b=credentialList.get(i).getString("SurName");
                    persons.add(new Person(a,b));



                    Log.d("OUT", "So the Val::------> " +a +b);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    //persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old"));
    //persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old"));
    //persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old"));

}

private void initializeAdapter(){

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And I am able to log the Values that I receive from Cloud, also, the code works fine if I using some pre-defined values. As you can see the commented lines:

> ```
>    //persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old"));
>    //persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old"));
>    //persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old"));
> ```

And, here is the code to the Adapter class:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    //ImageView personPhoto;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        //personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
    }
}

List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).surname);
   // personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if(persons!=null)
    {
        return persons.size();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

And the Person class :

```
    class Person
{
    String name;
    String surname;


    Person(String name, String sur)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = sur;

    }
}
```

Though I use an `notifyDataSetChanged()` method, why am I not able to get any result, should I consider using a different thread or `AsyncTask()` , looking for Answers, Thanks !

Comment: Try moving `initializeAdapter();` before `initializeData();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are not actually setting the data into the adapter. First off add the following method inside of your adapter :

```
public void setPersons(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Then after the initializeData() method in your calling class just call `adapter.setPersons(persons)`. You don't have to call the following again:

```
`private void initializeAdapter(){

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}`
```

So basically just call `adapter.setPersons(persons)` whenever you get new data from the server.